# Creating a new column in one dataframe by selecting from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one dataframe that contains daily sales, but it contains hundreds of rows for each date due to some categorical grouping. Below is a rough idea of the dataframe structure.

```
2021-05-04  A  56
2021-05-04  B  40
2021-05-05  B  40
2021-05-07  A  20
```

I have another dataframe that contains economic indicators for every day this year, which looks like the sample below.

```
2021-05-04  1.4
2021-05-05  1.8
2021-05-06  2.2
```

I want to add the economic indicator as a new column in the original dataframe for every row, but I cannot figure out how to do it. This is the code I have tried but I get an error.

```
df1['Rate'] = df1.apply(lambda row: df2[df2['Date'] == row.Date]['Indicator']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend reading [this article](https://medium.com/swlh/merging-dataframes-with-pandas-pd-merge-7764c7e2d46d) about the merge.

In your case the following code should do the job:

```py
result_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="Date", how="left")
result_df.rename({"indicator": "Rate"}, inpace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just join the datasets on the date: `df1.merge(df2)`

Answer (score 0):

we can use **`map()`** on the `date` column of `df1`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2021-05-04', '2021-05-04', '2021-05-05', '2021-05-07'],
 'item': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A'],
 'sale': [56, 40, 40, 20]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2021-05-04', '2021-05-05', '2021-05-06'],
 'indicator': [1.4, 1.8, 2.2]})


df1['indicator'] = df1.date.map(dict(zip(df2.date, df2.indicator)))
```

Output:

```
    date    item    sale    indicator
0   2021-05-04  A   56        1.4
1   2021-05-04  B   40        1.4
2   2021-05-05  B   40        1.8
3   2021-05-07  A   20
```